# iTextSharp tables alignment when tables get large

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I am building a survey application. Where I am stuck now is that my client needed to create a printout of the final report made on the basis of survey. So he wanted to have his report converted to PDF. I used iTextSharp for that. The problem is when I try my algorithm of PDF generation for limited number of fields, everything remains exactly I want to. But as the table grow large, let say 50 fields the table orderings distort. This is my algorithm.

I have a `PdfPTable mainTable` with following properties:

```
PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(1);
mainTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
//mainTable.TotalWidth = 500f; //I tried increasing its total width but no use.
mainTable.TotalWidth = 100f;
mainTable.LockedWidth = true;
mainTable.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
```

Next I have `headerTable` which sports two images on the top and a welcome line:

```
PdfPTable headerTable = new PdfPTable(2);
headerTable.TotalWidth = 500f;
headerTable.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
headerTable.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 250f, 250f };
headerTable.SetWidths(widths);
```

After adding text and other things, I add the header table to my `mainTable`:

mainTable.AddCell(headerTable);

Now this is where problem starts. I create another table named `dataTable`. This table contains all the fields.

```
PdfPTable DataTable = new PdfPTable(2);
DataTable.TotalWidth = 500f;
DataTable.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
DataTable.LockedWidth = true;
widths = new float[] { 200f, 300f };
DataTable.SetWidths(widths);
```

After adding a lot of cells to it in the end I add this table to my main table above. The problem is all the formatting within the `dataTable` is perfect, but as soon as I have big data the first page only contains data till headerTable in the mainTable's 1st page. The datatable is printed on the next page. I have tried a lot of things, but cannot figure out where is the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance everybody!

Comment: Your question is phrased in a way that makes it impossible for me to understand what you're asking, even after reading it three times. Your code contains irrelevant lines, such as `setWidthPercentage()` whereas you define a total width (one excludes the other). You are trying to insert a table with total width 500 into a table with total width 100. You are nesting tables, which should be totally unnecessary. All of this makes it very hard for an outsider to help you.

Comment: Basically I am myself confused what should be the correct settings of the table etc. I tried a lot of things. I have set Document's page size A4 by doing this: `Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);` then I tried to set the MainTable's width as the total page, so I set the `WidthPercentage = 100`. But still nothing is helping out.

Comment: Bro, the issue is this:
- When I try to add few fields they all appear to be on the same page.
- But as soon as I try to print more fields on the main page, ONLY the headerTable is added to the MAINTABLE and the remaining DataTable is added but on the next page, not on the same page below the HeaderTable.

Suggest me if you can suggest what should be the correct values for the above issue.

Comment: I'm not your Bro. I'm the original author of iText and I explained what was wrong with your design. The behavior you see is caused by the fact that you insist on nesting tables (which is a bad design choice).

Comment: So you suggest I should create different tables for different things and add all of them to the main Document? This is the correct way?

Comment: Do you _need_ multiple tables in the first place? Could you just get away with one large table and `colspan` when needed?

Comment: I need multiple tables, in my understanding. Y? Because I have a header on first page(which has some logos) and then follows a list of fields with its title and values. For list I have a table with two columns. I thought about using different tables so as two keep things simple. If you can suggest a more simplified way, i would really appreciate that.